# Force update in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

How can I force Hibernate to update an entity instance even if the entity is *not* dirty? I'm using Hibernate 3.3.2 GA, Hibernate Annotations and Hibernate EntityManager btw. I really want Hibernate to execute the generic UPDATE statement even if no property on the entity has changed.

I need this because some event listeners need to get invoked to do some additional work when the application runs for the first time.

Thanks!

Answer (score 14):

ok - found it myself. This does the trick:

```
Session session = (Session)entityManager.getDelegate();  
session.evict(entity);  
session.update(entity);
```

Comment: +1 I had heard about the trick before, but couldn't recall it.

Comment: Neat trick but I just tried it and it is worth while to point out that if you are also interested in having this commit "entity.childEntity" it will not--it breaks the dependency tree.

Answer (score 4):

For transients, you can check

```
if(session.contains(entity)) {
  session.evict(entity);
}
session.update(entity);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
session.evict(entity);  
session.update(entity);
```

Good trick, but watch out for transient objects before putting this into some automation code. For transients I have then StaleStateObjectException

Answer (score 0):

Try em.flush() which is used for EJB 3.0 entities, which also uses JPA similar to Hibernate 3.2.2 GA. If it doesn't work normally, use flush in transactions.

Comment: Flush forces Hibernate to synchronize the changes in memory with the database. But if Hibernate does not consider the entity as dirty, it won't flush anything so far I remember.

Comment: yep - flush()ing does not help here as no changes are made